# The interference pattern of a wave along a line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, interference

Why the answer is B, but not C?
Is it true that the pattern cannot go beyond $A_0$ and $-A_0$ at the same instant?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The integral of both initial waves must be ~0 (it is cancelled out) and adding those two together yields a 0 integral too. So the resulting wave-function must be symmetric. Also, energy conservation implies that the amplitude must be $\sqrt 2 A_0$.

So answer C seems to be correct.